# DataGridView is not displaying my delete button

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a problem in my 2nd load of data using a DataGridView.

Here is my DataGridView and has a delete button when the data is first loaded:

[image]

On my 2nd load of data, this is the error I get:

[image]

After I click `Ok`, this is what happens in my DataGridView:

[image]

The delete button is gone.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub loaddata()
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    con.ConnectionString = "server=192.168.1.10;database=orderingsystem;username=server;password=server"
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataTable
    Dim source As New BindingSource
    Try
        con.Open()
        Dim query As String
        Dim total As Double
        Dim btn As New DataGridViewButtonColumn
        btn.HeaderText = "Action"
        btn.Text = "Delete"
        btn.Name = "btn"
        btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True

        query = "SELECT prodID, SUM(prodQty) as QTY, prodname as Name, prodPrice*SUM(prodQty) as Total from orderedlist where table_name = '" & Form1.Table_1.Name & "' GROUP BY prodID"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, con)
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(ds)
        source.DataSource = ds
        dgv_myOrder.DataSource = ds
        dgv_myOrder.Columns(0).Visible = False

        For i As Integer = 0 To dgv_myOrder.Rows.Count - 1
            total += Convert.ToDecimal(dgv_myOrder.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value).ToString("0.00")

        Next
        dgv_myOrder.Columns.Add(btn)

        lbl_Total.Text = Decimal.Parse(total).ToString("0.00")
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub dgv_myOrder_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv_myOrder.CellClick

    If e.RowIndex = dgv_myOrder.NewRowIndex Or e.RowIndex < 0 Then
    ElseIf e.ColumnIndex = dgv_myOrder.Columns("btn").Index Then

        Dim connection As String = "server=192.168.1.10;database=orderingsystem;username=server;password=server;"
        Dim con2 As New MySqlConnection(connection)
        con2.Open()

        Dim data As String = dgv_myOrder.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString
        Label2.Text = data

        Dim rd2 As MySqlDataReader
        Dim cmd2 As New MySqlCommand("UPDATE orderedlist SET cancelstatus = 1 WHERE prodID = '" & Label2.Text & "' and table_name = '" & Form1.Table_1.Name & "'", con2)

        rd2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader
        con2.Close()
        con2.Open()

        Dim rd3 As MySqlDataReader
        Dim cmd3 As New MySqlCommand("UPDATE tableassistance SET cancellation = 1 WHERE table_name = '" & Form1.Table_1.Name & "'", con2)

        rd3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader

        MessageBox.Show("Wait for confirmation!", "System")
        Me.Close()
        Label2.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

I call **`loaddata()`** in my form load.

Comment: 1) Clear `Columns` collection before setting `DataSource`. Or better option → 2) Set up `DataGridView` columns just once and use `LoadData` method to just load data.

Comment: Why do you create a BindingSource, set its DataSource property and then never use it?

Answer (score 0):

First remove this Line:

```
  dgv_myOrder.Columns.Add(btn)
```

Don't add the button to datagridview inside code create it form the designer and  use binding for other columns.

Steps :

1 . Create all your datagrdiview columns , using add columns button  in the top right of the datagridview

[this is how you add columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3ozV.png)

2 .after you add the columns , bind every column to its related Column in database like this , you can get this window when you click on EditColumns in datagidview designer , change the `DataPropertyName` in the properties of each column change it to the name of the datatable column name that you want it to preview but not add it to the delete column button:

[Binding the columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YI4yi.png)

3 . go to the properties of your delete button column in the datagridview you will find property called `DefalutCellStyle` inside it will find `NullValue`  change it to "Delete".

[Change the null value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao1pe.png)